# Como hacer que una Función funcione después de N veces seleccionada

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen día, estoy buscando hacer que una **Función** que me imprime del 1 al 10(No en lista) solo 1 numero por click en el boton consecutivamente hasta el 10, El código que tengo lo que hacer es imprimirme dentro de un rango del 1 al 10. Solo el 1, Luego al presionar el botón de nuevo imprime el 2.

**Lo que busco** es que aumente del 1 al 2 después de por ejemplo clickear el botón 4 veces.

Ejemplo:

Por defecto: 1

Luego de presionar el botón 4 veces se imprimirá el numero: 2

Luego de presionar el botón 4 veces se imprimirá el numero: 3

y así sucesivamente.

Con este código me imprime de los números cada numero +1 pero como haría para lograr lo que busco?

```
def pri():
    global i
    if i > 10:
        i = 1
    print(i)
    i+=1
i = 1
```

Comment: No entendí, quieres que suba un contador cada 4 clicks?

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: @rockbass2560 Exacto, despues de por ejemplo 4 clicks, imprima el numero 2

Comment: La función pri es la que está enlazada al click?

Comment: @rockbass2560 Exacto, Aclaro un poco, sobre el click me refiero al click sobre el boton. cada 4 veces en que se presiona el boton(Tkinter)

Answer (score 1):

Que confuso... supongo que lo que se quiere es una función que tome un parametro de entrada  y lo incremente si es que la función ha sido llamada 4 veces. Quiza iniciando una variable `contador = 0` y luego:

```
def cuarta_la_vencida():
    global contador
    
    contador += 1
    return contador % 4 == 0
```

Esta funcion retornará 1 si es que la cuenta de la variable global `contador` ha llegado a un valor multiplo de 4. Asi se puede utilizar para acumular una variable `num = 0`:

```
num += cuarta_la_vencida()    
print(num)
```

Luego de ejecutar 4 veces esta llamada el valor de num se incrementará en 1.

Comment: Gracias por respoder,el  `num+=...` va fuera de la funcion verdad?. declare `contador = 0` fuera del `def`, Pero al ejecutar me marca de error que `num` no esta definido. Cual podria ser el error?. Eh declado tambien `num = 0` pero despues de los 4 clicks en el boton no me imprime el siguiente numero que seria 2

Comment: Si observas la función, esta solo devuelve 1 o 0 (un valores booleano), no suma ni modifica un valor y su respuesta depende del numero de veces que es ejecutada según un valor de referencia (`contador`). Si quieres utilizarla para que sume un número, este tendrá que ser definido en el script y acumulado utilizando la operación +=.